# How to set date between AM/PM 24-hour

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

[image]

I have 2 parameters. one is defaultFromD and another is defaualtToD. if I give 2 date range for this  `x.CreatedOn >= defaultFromD && x.CreatedOn <= defaultToD`

> x.CreatedOn >= '2021-10-17' && x.CreatedOn <= '2021-10-20'

its working. but if I give same date for this two parameters this condition is not working.

> x.CreatedOn >= '2021-10-20' && x.CreatedOn <= '2021-10-20'

I want to knw how to pass this 2 logic in one condition. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you...

```
  public ResponseDTO<IQueryable<LabRequestForLabOrderDTO>> GetApprovedLabRequestsQueryable(DateTime defaultFromD, DateTime defaultToD)
    {
        var resp = ResponseBuilder.Build<IQueryable<LabRequestForLabOrderDTO>>();
        var reqs = this.labRequestRepository.GetAllActive().Where(x => x.IsActive && x.TrxStatus == 1 && x.InvoiceStatus == "Approved"
                        && x.CreatedOn >= defaultFromD && x.CreatedOn <= defaultToD)
                .Select(x => new LabRequestForLabOrderDTO
                {
                    Clinic = x.Clinic,
                    LabOrderCreated = x.LabOrderCreated,
                    InvoiceStatus = x.InvoiceStatus,
                    CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn
                }).AsQueryable();

        resp.AddSuccessResult(reqs);
        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: Post the code as text and explain what you want to retrieve. If you query a database post the table schema, especially the field type. `x.CreatedOn >= '2021-10-20' && x.CreatedOn <= '2021-10-20'` is equivalent to `x.CreatedOn = '2021-10-20'` and may not match any record in the table. If `CreatedOn` was a `date` field it would match any row with that date. If it's a `datetime`, `datetime2` etc though, it will match rows that are *exactly* `2021-10-20 00:00:00.0000`

Comment: If, on the other hand, you try to filter an in-memory list, the query will only match items that match the value exactly, to the nanosecond

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: In client side there have date range selector. if I select same date for get to the records. data is not come. but if I select different range its working. I want to know how do if I give one date range

Comment: @ChathurangaRanasingha post the code as text, not hard-to-read images. Images can't be copied, compiled and debugged. The problem is caused by the field type, not the client. What is `CreatedOn`? If it's a table column what is its type? If it has a time component the query will have to change to `x.CreatedOn >=date.Date && x.CreatedOn < date.Date.AddDays(1)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "CreatedOn" type is DateTime

Comment: Post the code as text!!!!!!! The property may be a `DateTime` but what about the *table*? If it's also a `DateTime` this query will never work, because the server will search for exact matches, not entries that are in the same day

Comment: Seriously, post the code and table schema as text. Trying to answer this is like pulling teeth

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I has post the code as a text. table column type is DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me

```
var todate = defaultToD.AddDays(1);

x.CreatedOn >= defaultFromD && x.CreatedOn <= todate
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<=` in `x.CreatedOn <= todate` otherwise it will match any date after defaultFromD and `x.CreatedOn >= todate` is redundant?

Comment: @phuzi  Yes. You correct. typing mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated your question with the typo fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
x.CreatedOn.AddDays(-1) > defaultFromD && x.CreatedOn.AddDays(1) < defaultToD
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to DateTime and Date Formate.

You should try the following way.

Consider you column CreatedOn datatype is: DateTime

```
x.CreatedOn.Date >= '2021-10-20' && x.CreatedOn.Date <= '2021-10-20'
```

Comment: I tried. It's doesn't work

Comment: Can you please your sample data of CreatedOn dates?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you.

Comment: Share your table sample data which you required to coming in this condition. x.CreatedOn >= '2021-10-20' && x.CreatedOn <= '2021-10-20'